# Print a mySQL query in a form

Tags: php, mysql, html, echo

Sorry, newbie question I know, however I've currently got mySQL results only showing when using the echo command through PHP etc..

Now, I am able to source the information fine, however I would like the result of a query to show up in a form e.g.

Rather than :-

```
    $loggedinuser = $session->username;

    //$query = "SELECT surname, firstname FROM PASSENGER WHERE username = '$jared'";
    $query2 = "SELECT p.surname, f.destination FROM PASSENGER p, FLIGHT_INFO f WHERE p.username = '$loggedinuser' AND p.flightNo = f.flightNo";
    $result = mysql_query($query2);  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['surname'] ." ". $row['destination'];
}

    echo mysql_error();
```

I would like to print the SQL result in a HTML form...e.g. one that follows the convention of:-

```
    Surname: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="echo $row['surname']/>
```

If you see where I am coming from. Is this really bad practice using forms to display mySQL results, or can it be done? If not really, what ways would you recommend I print the data? In a table of some sort, but how can I then use fields?

Regards,

Tom.

Something like this work:-

```
                            <?php

                    $loggedinuser = $session->username;

            //$query = "SELECT surname, firstname FROM PASSENGER WHERE username = '$jared'";
            $query2 = "SELECT p.surname, f.destination FROM PASSENGER p, FLIGHT_INFO f WHERE p.username = '$loggedinuser' AND p.flightNo = f.flightNo";
        $result = mysql_query($query2);  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

  "<form>"
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo {$row['surname']} ?>" disabled       />
     "</form>"
           }
               echo mysql_error();
       ?>
```

How can a new line be added between echo's in the following code please?

```
                echo ' Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].  "\" disabled /> ";
        echo 'Forename: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['forename']. "\" disabled />";
        echo 'Email Address: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['emailAddress']. "\" disabled />"; 
        echo 'Preference ID: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['dob']. "\" disabled />"; 
        echo 'Seat Number: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['seatNo']. "\" disabled />"; 
        echo 'Group ID: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['groupID']. "\" disabled />";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input value="<?php echo $row["firstname"]; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php print($row['surname']); ?>"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?=$row['surname']?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using anything to display the information is good, until you are not allowing the users to be able to change those values. You can also display using tables/divs or anything else you can think of. Forms are a very good method too(imo). Also, you can use a `disabled` property, to not to allow anyone to change those values you put in your Form's input boxes.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo {$row['surname']} ?>" disabled />
```

**EDIT** Putting up the while loop here:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "Surname: <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"" . {$row['surname']} . "\" disabled />"
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code at the top as I'm not sure how to use the mini-markdown formatting on this version of the site I'm using (via phone). Would the updated code work..?

Answer (score 1):

If you are merely needing to display data in a read-only fashion, you don't really want to "show the query", you want to print the results of said query in a readable fashion. I'm sure there are certain instances where you would need to print SQL to the users, but those situations are probably rather slim. As others have said, it is also extremely poor practice to allow the user to submit any type of SQL and use it - the mantra is that any user input should always be considered malicious user input - you must validate and sanitize everything before you send it to your database.

This being said, it looks like you just want to show a form with results from your query, which you were incredibly close on. The only issue you may have is if your query returns 2 or more rows, in order to get PHP to automatically bind the submitted values to an array, you'll have to sequentially name them so they show up as: `firstname[0]` , `firstname[1]` and so on. Just start an int that you can increment through each time:

```
 $loggedinuser = $session->username;

 $query2 = "SELECT p.surname, f.destination FROM PASSENGER p, FLIGHT_INFO f WHERE p.username = '$loggedinuser' AND p.flightNo = f.flightNo";
 $result = mysql_query($query2);  
 $i = 0;

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $surname = $row['surname'];
    $destination = $row['destination'];
    echo '<input type="text" name="firstname[$i]" value="$surname" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="destination[$i]" value="$destination" />';
    $i++;
 }
```

Let's say you had two rows show up in your query, here's what would result (with added formatting):

```
<input type="text" name="firstname[0]" value="Bill" />
<input type="text" name="destination[0]" value="Rococo" />

<input type="text" name="firstname[1]" value="Mandy" />
<input type="text" name="destination[1]" value="Philadelphia" />
```

**EDIT:** To add newlines to the HTML being outputted, just add a `<br />` tag for each newline:

```
    echo '<input type="text" name="firstname[$i]" value="$surname" /><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query2 = "SELECT p.surname, f.destination FROM PASSENGER p, FLIGHT_INFO f WHERE p.username = '$loggedinuser' AND p.flightNo = f.flightNo";
    $result = mysql_query($query2);  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
           echo '<form>';
           echo ' Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].'/><br/>';
           echo ' Below is my Destination<br/>';
           echo ' Destination: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['destination '].'/>';
           echo '</form>';
       }
```

Try this

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you, how could I add a new line if I had it like the update in the code above... :)